# What is this encoding? 0x21

Tags: character-encoding, ascii, hex

I am reading about ASCII and the book said that `!` was represented as `0x21`.

Now I know that `!` is the binary `00100001` in the ASCII table, which is also `33` in decimal, which converted to hex is `21`. But what is this `0x` part of the encoding `0x21`?

Comment: 0x refers most of the time to a hex representation. As you noticed already.

Comment: C (and C based) Languages use 0x to denote a hex value.

Comment: Correct, `0x21` is equivalent to 33. Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-1

Comment: Ok so it's just a marker saying, "the following is a hex representation"?

Comment: @fyr: What do you mean "most of the time"? When does it not indicate a hex representation?

Comment: Yes, `0x` is a common hexadecimal prefix.  `0` on its own is a common octal prefix.

Comment: Yes in code they are referred to as literal constants. You usually see them cross over into other things such as hex representation of a color in paint application. http://cpp.comsci.us/etymology/literals.html

Comment: @Richard like mentioned two comments above. It is a "common" prefix. But common means also that people tend to abuse common usage. So always verify what someone states it to be while coding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`0x` is the prefix used for hexadecimal numbers in almost every C-like programming language, so it has become the de-facto standard when writing hex numbers.

Sometimes you may also find hexadecimal numbers denoted by the `h` suffix (many assembly dialects follow this convention), or (in BASIC dialects) by the `&H` prefix.

Comment: Why are they encoded into Hex? What would it be used for? Why not just use their binary or decimal values?

Comment: @Richard: hex is often used for values that have some particular significance in binary because hex is compact b the conversion from/to hex is straightforward. Also, groups of bits multiple of 4 stay in fixed length hex numbers (one "normal" byte is always two hex digits).

Comment: @Richard thats pretty easy developers are lazy. And numbers to the base of 16 are shorter than numbers to the base of 10 or 8 or 2 ... :) and they also can be easily translated to a binary string. Because every hex character can be translated to a 4 character binary respresentation.

Comment: Other than these motivations, in reality often hex is used for constants for no other reason than being "cool" and `1337` :)